# how do I change the attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this input tag

```
<input type="hidden" name="find[0][1]" value="" id="findID" />
```

and I want to change the value of it using jQuery. How would I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#findId").val("whatever value you want");
```

Answer (score 1):

To change or set the value of attribute

```
$('div').attr('id','value')
```

To get the value of an attribute

```
$('div').attr('id')
```

If you want to change or edit the value of an input then use `val()`

```
$('#findID').val('your text')
```

Comment: @Autolycus give your input an id or class like `<input class="test" ../>` or id `<input id="test" ../>` then with jquery you reference it like `$('#test').val('your text') // assuming you are using an id`. Remember you can only use id once but you can use class as many times. If you do not reference your inputs and you do `$('input').val('whatever')` then this will apply to all inputs on your page.

Comment: @autolycus did you try `$('#findID').val('your text')`

Comment: @autolycus It doesn't really help Hussien by saying "doesnt work ..i tried it" Tell us what you tried? Where you tried it? What JavaScript errors are you getting? Did anything happen different? etc etc. I have tried a very simple version of your problem that works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/vsHEQ/  Although i had to change it to a text input to read it there will be no difference for your code.